# VS 2010 and .Net 4.0: Where's the Ajax Control Toolkit (Tab Control)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tabs

I know this is a newbie question, but where is the ASP.Net/Ajax tab control?

I used NuGet to install the Ajax Tool Kit. Visual Studio has 'Ajax Extensions' in its Toolbox, but the extensions only include ScriptManager, Timer, and UpdatePanel. I believe I'm missing the actual Ajax Controls Tab in the Toolbox.

I also appear to lack the 'Ajax Control Toolkit Template' for creating a new project under Visual Studio. It makes it hard to follow along with ASP.Net tutorials (such as Tab Control: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/ajax-control-toolkit/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-tabs-control).

EDIT: It appears I was missing a few pieces of the puzzle (namely, NuGet does not really install anything in a reusable manner). http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/ajax-control-toolkit/how-do-i-get-started-with-the-aspnet-ajax-control-toolkit and http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/04/16/installing-ajax-control-toolkit-4-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if NuGet is supposed to add controls to the toolbox as well, but you can add them manually.

Right click on the toolbox, create a new tab, right click on it and select "add items". Then browse to toolkit dll and select it, it will add the controls to the toolbox.

**EDIT**: I just added a reference to the library through NuGet, and I discovered that the package reference adds this to your web config:

```
<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

This means that when you start typing

```
<ajaxToolkit:
```

In your aspx (or ascx) files, you should see the auto-completion list for controls in the toolkit.

About the dll location, click on the reference in the solution explorer and check its path in the properties window.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now things get even lamer: I used NuGet to install, but I don't know what was installed where (I assumed it was the Ajax Extensions). Would you happen to have the name of the DLL? My apologies.

Comment: "I just installed the library through NuGet, and I discovered that the package reference adds this to your web config". Ajax was installed through NuGet earlier. The new project does not let me install/reinstall, so the new project is missing this stuff. I'd expected it to be easy - install the controls, and drag a control onto the page in the designer. Boy was I wrong! Its too bad that Microsoft has made this so difficult.